# Prove that det(A)=det(A1(1))

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a square matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $A\times1_{n\times 1}= 1_{n\times 1}$ (where $1_{n\times 1}$ is the vector with all entries equal to $1$). The matrix $\tilde{A}$ is obtained from $A$ by replacing the first column of $A$ by $1_{n\times 1}$. Prove that $\det A = \det \tilde{A}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.**

The assumption tells you that the vector $1_{n\times 1}$ is the sum of the columns of $A$.

Use the property that the determinant is linear in each of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

The premise implies that the first column is $1_{n\times1}$ minus the sum of the remaining columns. Adding the sum of the remaining columns to the first column is a column operation and doesn't change the determinant.